# bash while-for loop not executing correctly

Tags: bash, loops

This is my 1st `bash` script and I would appreciate some feedback.

```
#!/bin/bash
set yname="Would you like a cup of tea?"
while ($yname != "n")
   echo -n "Are you sure?"
   set yname = $<5
   else ($yname != "y") then
          echo "Great, I'll make tea now"
   endif
```

I am trying to create a script where you ask if someone would like a cup of tea. 
If the person replies 'n' the loop repeats. 
If the person replies 'y' the loop ends with the y output 
The loop repeats 5 times unless y is typed as an output.

Can anyone help me correct the above script or any feedback on it?

Struggling to find any support for this online.

Comment: Is that the full code? There seems to be something missing as there is no `if` for the `endif`. Furthermore, this is `bash`, not `vim` or `putty`-related.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Hi many thanks for your reply. Apologies about the incorrect terms, this is all new to me. Yes  you are correct it is bash that I am using. I have managed to tweak the script to output but I need to get it to loop: 


    'END=5
    echo "Would you like a cup of tea?"
    read answer

    if [ $answer = n ]
       then
       echo "Are you sure?"
    elif [ $answer = y  ]
       then echo "Great, I'll make tea now"

    fi'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your script several ways, but this is one approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
_ANSWER=""
_COUNT=0
while [ "${_ANSWER}" != "y" -a ${_COUNT} -lt 5 ] ; do
    _COUNT=$(( ${_COUNT} + 1 ))
    read -p "Would you like a cup of tea? " _ANSWER
    if [ "${_ANSWER}" == "y" ] ; then
        echo "Great, I'll make tea now"
    else
        echo "Are you sure?"
    fi
done
```

Hopefully, this will introduce you to some common shell script methods.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply Leslie, it is very much appreciated.
Yes I am extremely fresh when it comes to shell scripts, hoping to improve as I go. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful.  If you don't mind, it's customary on Stack Overflow to "accept" an answer if you're happy with it.